# Calculate surface integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

I need some help with the following:

Given $$f(x,y,z)=\left(
\frac{-x}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}, \frac{-y}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac32}}, \frac{-z}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac32}}
\right),$$ calculate the flow rate of fuid out of the total surface
$S$, where $$S=\{(x,y,z)\; | \; x^2+y^2+z^2=1 \}.$$

I got $\displaystyle \frac{4\pi}{3}$ but I think I messed up with the normal vector.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I believe it is flipped. It should be the negative of ur answer. You can see this by the paramerization to spherical coordinates with the position vector $r (\phi , \theta) $ and taking $r_\theta X r_\phi $ you see this is the outward normal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
Note that
$\ds{\vec{\fermi}\pars{x,y,z}=-\,{\vec{r} \over r^{3}}=\nabla\pars{1 \over r}}$ where
$\ds{\vec{r} \equiv x\,\hat{x} + y\,\hat{y} + z\,\hat{z}}$.

> \begin{align}
> \color{#66f}{\large\int_{\rm S}\vec{\fermi}\pars{x,y,z}\cdot\dd\vec{\rm S}}&
> =\int_{\rm V}\nabla\cdot\vec{\fermi}\pars{x,y,z}\,\dd^{3}\vec{r}
> =\int_{\rm V}\nabla\cdot\nabla\pars{1 \over r}\,\dd^{3}\vec{r}
> \\[5mm]&=\int_{\rm V}\nabla^{2}\pars{1 \over r}\,\dd^{3}\vec{r}
> =\int_{\rm V}\bracks{-4\pi\,\delta\pars{\vec{r}}}\,\dd^{3}\vec{r}
> =\color{#66f}{\large -4\pi}
> \end{align}

A $\ds{\tt\mbox{direct calculation}}$ is given by:
$$
\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{r\ =\ 1}\pars{-\,{\vec{r} \over r^{3}}}\cdot\pars{r^{2}\, {\vec{r} \over r}}
\verts{\dd\vec{\rm S}}}
=-\int_{r\ =\ 1}\verts{\dd\vec{\rm S}}
=\color{#66f}{\large -4\pi}
$$

> Otherwise
>   $$
> \color{#66f}{\large%
> \int_{r\ =\ 1}\pars{-\,{\vec{r} \over r^{3}}}\cdot\dd\vec{\rm S}}
> =-\int_{r\ =\ 1}{\vec{r}\cdot\dd\vec{\rm S} \over r^{3}}
> =-\int_{r\ =\ 1}\dd\Omega_{\vec{r}}=\color{#66f}{\large -4\pi}
> $$